# Need to adjust Slider's thumb position according to the Audio playback state within Expo app

Tags: reactjs, audio, expo, slider, native

My app for Android, iOS and Web is built upon Expo (React Native).
I try to update Slider's thumb position (by changing the 'value' property) according to the audio playback progress.
But this part of code works only once, at the start of the PlayAudio() function call.
How can Slider's thumb position be adjusted to the playback state constantly?
Below is the code.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import { activateKeepAwake, deactivateKeepAwake } from "expo-keep-awake";

import AudioTouchable from "./AudioTouchable";
import Slider from "@react-native-community/slider";

export default function ChapterAudio({ chapterAudio }) {
  const LoadAudio = async () => {
    try {
      UnloadAudio();

      await audio.current.loadAsync({ uri: chapterAudio }, {}, true);
      audio.current.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(UpdateAudio);
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  const PlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const audioStatus = await audio.current.getStatusAsync();

      if (audioStatus.isLoaded && audioStatus.isPlaying === false) {
        audio.current.playAsync();
        activateKeepAwake();
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  const PauseAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const audioStatus = await audio.current.getStatusAsync();

      if (audioStatus.isLoaded) {
        if (audioStatus.isPlaying === true) {
          audio.current.pauseAsync();

          deactivateKeepAwake();
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  const StopAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const audioStatus = await audio.current.getStatusAsync();

      if (audioStatus.isLoaded) {
        PauseAudio();
        audio.current.setPositionAsync(0);
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  const UnloadAudio = async () => {
    try {
      await audio.current.unloadAsync();
      deactivateKeepAwake();
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  const UpdateAudio = async (playbackStatus) => {
    if (playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      try {
        const audioDuration = playbackStatus.durationMillis;
        const audioPosition = playbackStatus.positionMillis;
        const positionRatio = audioPosition / audioDuration;

        setSliderValue(positionRatio);
      } catch (e) {}
    }

    playbackStatus.didJustFinish && deactivateKeepAwake();
  };

  const audio = React.useRef(new Audio.Sound());
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = React.useState(0);

  LoadAudio();

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.player}>
        <AudioTouchable name="play" onPress={PlayAudio} />
        <AudioTouchable name="pause" onPress={PauseAudio} />
        <AudioTouchable name="stop" onPress={StopAudio} />
      </View>
      <Slider
        style={{ width: "100%", paddingTop: 30, height: 60 }}
        minimumValue={0}
        maximumValue={1}
        minimumTrackTintColor="#555555"
        maximumTrackTintColor="#AAAAAA"
        thumbTintColor="teal"
        value={sliderValue}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  player: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```